# Objective-C and global variables

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

I am reading a book on Objective-C, paragraph dedicated to the global variables.

Author uses the following example:

For class `Employee`

In `.h` file declare:

```
extern NSString const *greeting;
```

In `.m` file declare

```
NSString const *greeting = @"Hello";
```

Author however does not mention the need for

```
@property (strong, readonly) NSString const *greeting;
```

and `@synthesize greeting;`

Am i missing something and there is a way to avoid it, or was that a typo on the author's part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@property is for instance variables; global variables are not specific to an instance of a class. Even then, you do not need to use @property, even for instance variables.

Comment: That's what i thought, however, variable is not visible from outside of the class for some reason. After i `Eployee *e = [Employee new];` `[e greeting]` is not visible

Comment: @James: Do not call `[e greeting]`. The `Employee` class does not contain that property. To access the `greeting` global variable, simply request it like `NSLog(@"%@", greeting);`

Answer (score 0):

Global variables aren't needed done in a class. Hence, you don't need a property.

Comment: How can i use this global variable from outside of the Employee class?